# append a String on ArduinoJson Object value

Tags: arduino-uno, c, string, json

I've a json string request coming from server and I convert it into json object

```
  StaticJsonBuffer<500> jsonStaticBuffer;
  JsonObject& root = jsonStaticBuffer.parseObject(String(msg));
  String reqId;
  String reqData;
  root["requestid"].printTo(reqId);
  root["data"].printTo(reqData);
```

I need to populate another char json string initiated at the beginning

```
const char response[] = "{\"response\": {\"requestid\":, \"data\":}}";
```

such that I need to write `requestid` into the `response::requestid` and `data` `into response::data + ACK/NAK` . here is how i've tried;

```
  DynamicJsonBuffer jsonDynResponse; 
  JsonObject& jsonResponse = jsonDynResponse.parseObject(response);   
  String out;  
  if (ACK) {
      jsonResponse["response"]["requestid"] = root["requestid"]; 
      jsonResponse["response"]["data"] = root["data"] + " ACK"; //THIS DOESN'T WORKS
      jsonResponse.printTo(out);       
  } else {
      jsonResponse["response"]["requestid"] = reqId;
      jsonResponse["response"]["data"] = reqData + " NAK";  
      jsonResponse.printTo(out);  
  }
```

I know this will definitely not work `root["data"] + " ACK"` because we can't combine const char with String. But this `reqData + " NAK";` resulted in `"\"data\" NAK""`. How can I concate root["data"] into another String ? 
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `String(root["data"]) + " ACK"`?

Comment: Tried that already, I get `exit status 1
call of overloaded 'String(ArduinoJson::Internals::JsonObjectSubscript<const char*>)' is ambiguous`

Comment: perhaps you need to create a `String` variable, do things with it, and then `jsonResponse["response"]["data"] = whateverYourStringVariableIsCalled;`

Comment: The `things` that I want to do with the string is `append ACK/NAK` on whatever is in root["data"]. Which I am not able to do.